# Async Actions resolve before fetch result is retrieved

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, redux, promise, redux-thunk

I'm using Redux with `redux-thunk` to retrieve categories from an API. I have an action called `viewCategory` that depends on having categories in the store state.

I used the example of fetching Reddit posts from the Redux site:
https://redux.js.org/advanced/asyncactions#actions-js-asynchronous

The problem I have is that when I call `viewCategory` the promise thinks it's resolved when `REQUEST_CATEGORIES` is dispatched and not `RECEIVE_CATEGORIES`. So if log my state in the `then` statement I have an 
empty list of categories.

```js
export function viewCategory(urlKey) {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(fetchCategoriesIfNeeded()).then(() => {
            let state = getState();
            console.log(state); // should have categories
            let categories = [...state.categories.mainCategories,
                ...state.categories.specialCategories];
            let matchCategory = categories.find((category) => {
                return category.custom_attributes.find(x => x.attribute_code === "url_key").value === urlKey;
            });

            dispatch({
                type: Categories.VIEW_CATEGORY,
                category: matchCategory
            });
        });
    };
}
```

The functions that decide if categories should be fetched at all:

```js
function shouldFetchCategories(state) {
    const categories = state.categories;
    if(categories.isFetching || categories.mainCategories.length > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

export function fetchCategoriesIfNeeded() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        if(shouldFetchCategories(getState())) {
            return dispatch(fetchCategories());
        } else {
            return Promise.resolve();
        }
    };
}
```

The function that contains the actual fetch call:

```js
function fetchCategories() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        dispatch(requestCategories());
        const {locale} = getState().settings;
        return fetch(`${BASE_URL}/categories/list`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Accept-Language": locale
            },
            body: "Not interesting for stackoverflow"
        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                if(json !== undefined && json.items){
                    dispatch(receiveCategories(json.items));
                }
            });
    };
}
```

The functions where I dispatch types `REQUEST_CATEGORIES` & `RECEIVE_CATEGORIES`:

```js
function requestCategories() {
    return {
        type: Categories.REQUEST_CATEGORIES
    };
}

function receiveCategories(result) {
    const mainCategories = result.filter(category => category.level === 2);
    const subCategories = result.filter(category => category.level === 3);

    const categories = mainCategories.map(category => {
        let children = subCategories.filter(x => x.parent_id === category.id);
        return {
            ...category,
            children
        };
    });

    let specialCategories = categories.splice(categories.length - 2, 2);
    return {
        type: Categories.RECEIVE_CATEGORIES,
        categories: categories,
        specialCategories: specialCategories,
        receivedAt: Date.now()
    };
}
```

### [image: Redux Devtools action order]

Any idea what I am doing wrong here? If you need any extra code or information please let me know.

Comment: Please add the fetchCategories function's code

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! It should actually be `fetchCategoriesIfNeeded` so I updated that real quick. I can add the code for `fetchCategoriesIfNeeded` but that's nothing special. Do you want the function with the actual fetch?

Comment: Please add the code where you dispatch REQUEST_CATEGORIES and RECEIVE_CATEGORIES

Comment: Added! Appreciate you looking into this

Comment: Can you post the code for `fetchCategoriesIfNeeded` just to be complete?

Comment: @DavidKemp added both `fetchCategoriesIfNeeded` & `shouldFetchCategories`